# C# Entity Framework 6 loading related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want update the **student role** by the **received role id**.

The problem is that if I load the role instance before load the student instance, the entity role is included in the query and the entity was attached automatically and the update fails with this correct integrity message error (bottom).

```
 using (var ctx = new SchoolContext())
 {
    ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    var role = ctx.Role.Select(x => x).ToList(); 
    var student = ctx.Students.Include(s => s.Courses)
                              .Where(s => s.Id = id);

    student.RoleId = roleId;
    ctx.SaveChanges();            
 }
```

Error:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The
>   property value(s) of `Role.Id` on one end of a relationship do not
>   match the property value(s) of `Student.RoleId` on the other end.

I explicit use `LazyLoadingEnabled = false` but it doesn't work. I don't find a way for exclude the role in the query. The only way is load roles after...

Comment: can you share the structure of the students and role entity classes?

Comment: before setting `student.RoleId` that `roleId` already exists on database?

Comment: @Hanc
`var student = ctx.Students.Include(s => s.Courses)
                              .Where(s => s.Id = id);`  it should .`Where(s => s.Id == id)`

Comment: is roleId a passed in parameter? if so, select role by using var role = ctx.Role.SelectFirstOrDefault(x=> x.RoleId = roleId).RoleId and then try student.RoleId = role

Answer (score 0):

Try using the navigation property `Student.Role` instead of `Student.RoleId`:

```
var role = ctx.Role.Single(r => r.Id = roleId);
student.Role = role;
```

As a general rule of thumb: manipulate entity relations through the navigation properties instead of their foreign key properties.